# Intersection of arrays based on user selections with Raphael, jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, raphael

First time poster and just barely above a JavaScript/jQuery/Raphael novice. Please forgive me for any transgressions. :)

So, I've looked high and low for answers to my questions and have found some promising leads, but my programming skills are just too green to piece it all together. I've set up an interactive US map with Raphael and I'm giving users a set of 13 check boxes that ultimately highlight states based on various criteria. Each check box is associated with about 3 to 15 states (all paths, of course). When the user selects a handful of check boxes, I need to find the intersection of the arrays and highlight only those states. For example:

```
<input id="a1" value="arr1" type="checkbox" />
<input id="a2" value="arr2" type="checkbox" />
<input id="a3" value="arr3" type="checkbox" />
<input id="a4" value="arr4" type="checkbox" />
<input id="a5" value="arr5" type="checkbox" />

arr1 = [a,b,c];
arr2 = [b,c,d];
arr3 = [b,c,e];
arr4 = [a,e];
arr5 = [a,b];
```

If the user were to select a1, a2, and a3, for example, then I'd create another array for the intersection -- let's say, intArr = [b,c] -- and then change the fill color on the appropriate Raphael paths.

I was able to solve this by brute force and thanks to a clever intersection function that I found here. But for a more elegant solution, one saving me literally about 100 lines of code, I'm guessing I need to create an array of arrays (or objects?) based on user selections and then iterate over it to compare the first array to any others in the master array. There's a catch: I think I need the arrays to all be Raphael element variables. (Unless I need to give each element an id and somehow target them later for changing the fill attribute?)

Here is how I got it to work:

```
var selectedStates = new Array();
var arr1 = new Array(stArr1,stArr2,stArr3,stArr4,stArr5,stArr6);
var arr2 = new Array(stArr2,stArr3,stArr7,stArr9);
// etc.

var arr1Sel = false;
var arr2Sel = false;
// etc.

$('#selecttools input').click(function(){ 
  // reset all global variables for each feature
  arr1Sel = false;
  arr2Sel = false;
  // etc. 

  // find checked boxes and set appropriate globals to true
  $('#selecttools').find(":checked").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'arr1') { arr1Sel = true; }
    if ($(this).val() == 'arr2') { arr2Sel = true; }
    //etc.

  // now run selectTheStates
  selectTheStates();
});

function selectTheStates() {
  // first reset selectedStates with the default fill color
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedStates.length; i++) {
    selectedStates[i].attr({fill: "#CCB2E5"});
  }
  // setup the intersect filter
  // thank so much, love this one http://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/KpCt2/
  $.arrayIntersect = function(a, b) {
    return $.grep(a, function(i) {
      return $.inArray(i, b) > -1;
    });
  }
  // first make a list of selected arrays
  var ourFinalList = new Array();
  // now, the real brute force...nested if statements that have to go!
  if (arr1Sel == true) {
    ourFinalList = arr1;
    if (arr2Sel == true) { ourFinalList = $.arrayIntersect(ourFinalList,arr2) }
    if (arr3Sel == true) { ourFinalList = $.arrayIntersect(ourFinalList,arr3) }
    // etc.
  } else if (arr2Sel == true) {
    ourFinalList = arr2;
    if (arr3Sel == true) { ourFinalList = $.arrayIntersect(ourFinalList,arr3) }
    // etc. lots of nesting here, yuck!
  } else if (arr13Sel == true) {
    ourFinalList = arr13;
  }
  // now paint all the states in our final list with Raphael
  for (var i = 0; i < ourFinalList.length; i++) {
    ourFinalList[i].attr({fill: "#B38CD8"});
  }
  // last step is reset selectedStates
  selectedStates = ourFinalList;
// end selectTheStates
}
```

Believe it or not, this works. But the code is seriously bloated and looks so amateurish that I'm embarrassed to even post it here. But I really want to learn how to do this! Please help.

I'm guessing I need to make an array of the arrays, find the first array in that array and then compare/intersect it with any other arrays found in the array. I ran into several problems trying to do this, though. 1. Because I'm trying to make an array of variables that are in fact arrays, I seem to be pushing the values of the array (and not a placeholder for the arrays) into the master array. Maybe I need objects to do this?

Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

UPDATE

Special thanks to David. I finally got it to work. One trick I had to figure out:

David had suggested I do the following:

var selectedStates = selected.map(function() { return stateArrays[this]; });

It took some research, but I figured out I needed to double wrap my returned value or the entire array would push as a concat. So, this worked:

var selectedStates = selected.map(function() { return [stateArrays[this]]; });

After that, I just needed to iterate over the array of arrays, as he suggested. Although, I never did get pop(); to work for some reason. So, I just used selectedStates[0] as my first array for the intersection tool.

Many thanks again, David!

END UPDATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you'd want some way of getting finding out which arrays have been selected.

```
var selected = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() { return this.value; });
// selected = ['arr1','arr2','arr3'] for instance
```

I'm using `:checkbox:checked` to get all checked checkboxes since you're not showing any class names or anything that we could use to distinguish the checkboxes of interest. You might be better off using something like `.box-class:checked` or `#parent :checkbox:checked`.

From there, you want to turn your list of array names into a list of the actual arrays. As your code is right now, you've just created a bunch of variables named `arr1`, `arr2` etc. You might want to make those properties of an object instead:

```
var stateArrays = {
   arr1: [a,b,c],
   arr2: [b,c,d],
   ...
};
```

That way, you could access them in the following manner:

```
var x = stateArrays[myVariable];
// x = [a,b,c] if myVariable = 'arr1'
```

If you want to keep your separate variables, you could of course just create such an object anyway:

```
var stateArrays = {
   arr1: arr1, // where arr1 is already defined
   ...
};
```

So, in your scenario:

```
var selectedStates = selected.map(function() { return stateArrays[this]; });
// selectedStates = [[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[c,d,e]] for instance
```

Now you only need to loop over your array of arrays to get the intersect:

```
var result = selectedStates.pop();
selectedStates.forEach(function(x) {
   result = $.arrayIntersect(result, x);
});

// result = [c], given the value of selectedStates as above
```

The snippet above using `$.arrayIntersect` as you've defined it in your post.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the speedy response David! This looks very thoughtful. I will try to implement it soon and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help, David. I can't seem to get pop(); method to work. Any ideas? I've edited my original post above with details.

Comment: I did get it to work. Thanks David! I have a lot to learn. I'm glad people like you are willing to help!!